# Why am I getting compilation errors in this code?

Tags: c++

I have to write this program for class that takes in a C++ file, removes all the comments from the code and reads out the code to either a new file or in the output. After a long time of working on this, I keep receiving compilation errors, and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Some help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void remove_comments (ifstream& , ofstream&); //function declaration

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  string inputFileName;
  string outputFileName;
  string s;
  ifstream fileIn;
  ofstream fileOut;
  char ch;

  do
  {
    cout<<"Enter the input file name:";
    cin>>inputFileName;
  }
  while (fileIn.fail() );
  cout<<"Enter the output file name: ";
  cin>>outputFileName;

  fileIn.open(inputFileName.data());
  assert(fileIn.is_open() );
  remove_comments ( fileIn , fileOut);         

  fileIn.close();
  fileOut.close();

  return 0;
}


void remove_comments( ifstream& fileIn , ofstream& fileOut)
{
  string line;
  bool flag = false;

  while (! fileIn.eof() )
  {

    getline(fileIn, line);

    if (line.find("/*") < line.length() )
      flag = true;
    if (! flag)
    {
      for (int i=0; i < line.length(); i++)
      {

        if(i<line.length())
          if ((line.at(i) == '/') && (line.at(i + 1) == '/'))
          break;
          else
            fileOut << line[i];
      }
      fileOut<<endl;


  }
  if(flag)
  {
    if(line.find("*/") < line.length() )
      flag = false;
  }

}
```

The errors I get are:

```
In function 'void remove_comments(std::ifstream&,std::ofstream&)':
53: error: 'fileIn' was not declared in this scope
67: error: expected primary-expression before 'else'
67: error: expected `;' before 'else'
70: error: 'fileOut' was not declared in this scope
At global scope:
81: error: expected declaration before '}' token
```

Comment: What error are you recieving exactly?

Comment: Well, what's the error message?

Comment: Does your program handle [code like this](http://ideone.com/dgpB1l)?

Comment: Here are the errors: 

: In function 'void remove_comments(std::ifstream&,std::ofstream&)':

:53: error: 'fileIn' was not declared in this scope

:67: error: expected primary-expression before 'else'

:67: error: expected `;' before 'else'

:70: error: 'fileOut' was not declared in this scope

: At global scope:

:81: error: expected declaration before '}' token

Comment: If you write lots of code before you test any of it, you will fail. Start small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, test at every step, never add to code that doesn't work.

Comment: The error message explains exactly what is wrong. On line 53, you try to use `fileIn`, but there is no such variable.

Comment: Note that people expect programs to be compilable unless you identify in the question that you can't get it to compile. If you have compilation errors, always include the compilation error messages in the question; we shouldn't have to guess what problem you are seeing. It's usually a good idea to identify the compiler and operating system you're using too. Separately, one day you'll learn about the tricks people can do in programs, such as `puts("/* this is not a comment */");`, but you've bigger problems to worry about before you get into such refinements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
remove_comments( ifstream& , ofstream&)
```

you didn't write parameters names, it should be

```
remove_comments( ifstream& fileIn, ofstream& fileOut)
```

you also missed a couple of brackets at the end

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared in `main()` is not available to other functions.  Similarly with all functions.  This is called variable scope.

Your variable `fileIn` in `remove_comments` has no declaration inside the function, which is what the compiler is complaining about.  Perhaps, like @Ahmed Magdy Guda said, you forgot to put parameters in your function declaration and definition.